# How to know if a user liked a post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

Im using Facebook SDK for Android, and i want to know if a user (that is logged in, with read_stream permission) liked a post on facebook.
I try to use FQL, but not all posts return results, even if they are really liked (i went to facebook.com to check).
Any solutions?